# Which one is the correct pronunciation of the word ‘cabin’?

Tags: pronunciation

I am having trouble with the pronunciation. Which one is the correct pronunciation of the word ‘cabin’?

cabin /kæ bɪn/ /kæb ɪn/ /kæb bɪn/ /kæbɪn/

Comment: Hi @Learner. Welcome to the site. It is nearly always a good idea to include more detail in questions than you have included here. For example, any efforts you have made to work out the answer for yourself and any dictionaries you have consulted, and why you still need help. Doing so increases your chances of getting a good answer, and reduces the chances of your question receiving close votes.

Comment: 1,2 and 4 are the same, except for an unpronounced whitespace.  If you are producing 1,2 and 4 differently, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

All those are the correct pronunciations except /kab bɪn/. However, it's usually syllabified as /ˈkab.ɪn/ rather than /kæ.bɪn/ because English words don't usually end with the lax vowel /æ/ (and /ʊ ɪ ɛ ɒ/ etc), so the /b/ is usually syllabified as the coda ('end') of the first syllable.

Comment: Thank you. How about the using /b/ as ambisyllabic?

Comment: @Learner: That's also possible (I thought it might further confuse you so I didn't mention it)